# Show that $(n,x)$ is a prime ideal if and only if $n$ is a prime number $(R = \mathbb{Z}[x],n\geq 1$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $n\geq 1$.

Show that $(n,x)$ is a prime ideal if and only if $n$ is a prime number.

My proof:

$$\mathbb{Z}[x] = \{ a_o + a_1x^1 + ... + a_nx^n: n \in \mathbb{N}_0, a_0,...,a_n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$

Since $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a commutative ring,

$$(n,x) = (n) + (x)$$

where

$$(n) = \{ nk: k \in \mathbb{Z}\}, (x) = \{ a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_nx^2: n\in \mathbb{N}, a_1,...,a_n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

Hence,

$$(n) + (x) = \{ nk + a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_nx^n: n\in \mathbb{N}, a_1,...,a_n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

Let $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $pq \in (n,x)$. Then we can write $p,q$ and $pq$ as
$$ p = p_0 + p_1x + ... + p_mx^m, \mbox{ for some } m \in \mathbb{N} $$
$$ q =q_0 + q_1x + ... + q_rx^r \mbox{ for some } r \in \mathbb{N} $$
and their product as
$$ pq = p_0q_0 + c_1x + ... + c_kx^k, \mbox{ for } k = m + r, c_1,...,c_k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

By hypothesis $(n,x)$ is a prime ideal and $pq \in (n,x)$ hence

$$p \in (n,x), \mbox{ or }, q \in (n,x)$$

If $p \in (n,x)$ then
$$p = nk_p + p_1x + p_2x^2 + ... + p_mx^m, \mbox{ for some } k_p \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Hence, $nk_p = p_0 \Rightarrow n|p_0$ or $n=1$ and $k_p = p_0$. If $n = 1$ we have that $(n,x) = \mathbb{Z}[x]$. If $(n,x) = \mathbb{Z}[x]$ we contradict the assumption that $(n,x)$ is a prime ideal because prime ideals are proper. Hence, $n$ can not be one. We pick $p_0$ as an arbitrary integer, and $n$ divides $p_0$, hence $n$ must be prime.

It remains to proof that $n$ is prime if $q \in (n,x)$, but the proof is the same if we replace $p$ by $q$.

Now I dont know how to prove the other direction.

Can anyone verify this proof for me, and help me with the other direction?

Thanks!

Comment: To be more precise, $(n)=\{nP,P\in \Bbb Z[X]\}$. But the end result is the same since $(x)$ contains *all* multiples of $x$ anyway.

Comment: As for your own proof, it would be better to state clearly from the beginning what sense you prove first, what you assume and what you want to prove. I don't see what you want to say with the following sentence: "Hence, $nk_p = p_0 \Rightarrow n|p_0$ or $n=1$ and $k_p = p_0$."

Comment: I prove that $n$ divides an arbitrary integer $p_0$, and $n$ is not 1, then $n$ must be prime, since every number is product of primes. I am right ? @ArnaudMortier

Comment: *"Hence, n divides any arbitrary integer, and n is not 1, hence n must be prime"* No, primes don't divide any arbitrary integer. But fortunately, that is not what you proved, since $p_0$ is not completely arbitrary (there are conditions on the product $pq$).

Comment: Yeah its based on the conditions but how you justify that is prime then ?

Comment: With your kind of approach, you assume that it's not, this tells you what $p$ and what $q$ to consider.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $$\Bbb Z[x]/(n,x)\simeq \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$$
This gives you the equivalence right away, because an ideal is prime if and only if the quotient is...

Comment: Integral domain! Thanks!

Comment: @RichardClare You're welcome :)

Comment: I have been for hours trying to find the ring isomorphism with no luck. Can you give me a hint or a reference on how to construct such function? I know how to do it with ideals of one element, but with two elements I get stuck.

Comment: I know I only need an homomorphism (ring) from $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}_n$ such that $Kern(\phi) = (n,x)$ by first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @RichardClare send a polynomial $P$ to $P(0) \bmod n$.

Comment: @RichardClare You're very welcome!